# Connecting to Remote MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL Hosting with Hostinger.

I am trying to connect to Hostinger Server from WebhostingPad.

1. I have White List WebhostingPad IP in Hostinger
2. Added WebhostingPad IP under Hostinger Remote MySQL
3. Using Below Code to Connect to Hostinger My QL.
4. ```
   <?php

   error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
   ini_set("display_errors",1);
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
   $link = mysqli_connect('sql394.main-hosting.eu', 'u297914264_ameya', 'Am', 'u297914264_ameya')   or die(mysqli_connect_error());
   ```

I am Getting ERROR as:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in /home/easydial/public_html/remotemysql.php on line 6
> Connection timed out

Comment: PHP Code;

<?php
               
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
    ini_set("display_errors",1);
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
    $link = mysqli_connect('sql394.main-hosting.eu', 'u2979142', 'Ame', 'u2979142')   or die(mysqli_connect_error());
?>

Answer (score 0):

Your MySQL server is probably not configured to accept requests from the host you're trying to access it from.

Check the configuration for the server. Since you say the local machine can access it check where you permitted this and do the same for the ip of the online host.

Comment: Your MySQL server is probably not configured to accept requests from the host you're trying to access it from. : Already Added IP under WhiteList and also Under Remote MySQL.